# How to merge two columns from different dataframes into a new dataframe by a third key variable (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, key

I have these two dataframes:

df1 <-  data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), b=c(11,21,31,12,22,32,13,23,33))

df2 <- data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3), c=c(101,201,301,102,202,302,103,203,303))

I wanna merge the columns "b" and "c" into a new dataframe but using "a" as a key variable.

The expected results is this:

df.output <- data.frame(b=c(21,22,23), c=c(201,202,203))

I have already tried the join function from dplyr withour success.

Thanks,

quelemem

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Based on additional comments by OP, tweaking the original solution can achieve the desired output (although I think [@akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46509294/8475145) answer is the better one to choose in this context as no `nest` / `unnest` is required).

```r
library(tidyverse)
left_join(nest(df1, -a), nest(df2, -a), by = "a") %>% 
  filter(a == 2) %>% unnest() %>% select(-a)
#>    b   c
#> 1 21 201
#> 2 22 202
#> 3 23 203
```

**Original answer**

As @akrun mentions in the comments, the desired output is not entirely clear. 
 Do you mean something like this as output?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df3 <- left_join(nest(df1, -a), nest(df2, -a), by = "a")
df3
#>   a     data.x        data.y
#> 1 1 11, 12, 13 101, 102, 103
#> 2 2 21, 22, 23 201, 202, 203
#> 3 3 31, 32, 33 301, 302, 303
```

Comment: I would like to merge the columns "b" and "c" into a new dataframe, but select just the rows corresponding to the number 2 of the variable "a".  The expected result would be:                                                                                b   c
21  201
22  202
23  203

Comment: I have tried this solution, without success: library(plyr) 
df3 <- join(df1[,2], df2[,2], by = "a", type = "inner")

Comment: @quelemem, I've edited my answer based on the comments

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logic mentioned by the OP in the comments, we could `filter` only rows in 'a' with value 2, then `mutate` the column 'c' by getting the corresponding 'c' values were 'a' is 2

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(a == 2) %>%
   mutate(c = df2$c[a ==df2$a]) %>%
   select(-a)
#   b   c
#1 21 201
#2 22 202
#3 23 203
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
cbind(subset(df1, a==2, select = b), subset(df2, a==2, select = c))
```